# USERNAME folder missing, after accidentally moving Downloads folder to Users in C: drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, path, user-profiles, windows-error-reporting

[This](https://www.tenforums.com/user-accounts-family-safety/141721-user-profile-downloads-folder.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71344421/username-folder-missing-after-accidentally-moving-downloads-folder-to-users-in) is the actual problem, with the `%UserProfile%` folder renamed to `Download` and I cannot change it: [image: screenshot1]

- I'm also not able to access the `%UserProfile%\Download` folder from This PC: [image: Screenshot2]

Comment: Make a new, test Windows User Account and make it a member of Administrators.  Log in to the new Account, take Ownership of the folders in question and move the folders to c:\temp (make temp if you need to).  Then log in as yourself and see if you can recover your documents.

Comment: I don't think I would be able to do that myself, do you have any desk account, Instructions are not clear enough.

Comment: If instructions to make a new Account and take Ownership of the folders are beyond your regular capabilities, you should take the machine to a nearby computer shop and have them help you.

Comment: Without knowing precisely what caused this, although it's reminiscent of a corrupted Registry, the most efficient way to resolve this is to [create a new user profile](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-a-corrupted-user-profile-in-windows-1cf41c18-7ce3-12f9-8e1d-95896661c5c9) and migrate your data over to the new user profile once logged into it. Once a user profile becomes corrupted, there's no efficient way to fix it, especially if this is a result of a borked Registry edit since the user profile directory is referenced throughout the system and user Registry hives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a new account. Your profile folder accidentally acquired the `desktop.ini` file associated with the `Downloads` folder. The `desktop.ini` file specifies the dispay name and custom icon.

1. Open Explorer to `C:\Users` like in your first screenshot.
2. `<Shift>+<RIght-click>` in the *background* and select `Open PowerShell window here`.
3. Type `gci -ad<Enter>` to list directories. Most likely you'll see your UserProfile folder and not the `Downloads` folder. If so, precede.
4. Type the following, substituting the profile folder name:

   `(gi '<FolderName>').Attributes -= 'ReadOnly'`
5. That should turn off processing of the `desktop.ini` file and your profile folder should display it's true name once you close and re-open `Explorer`.

That should take care of the profile folder name issue.

---

The missing `Downloads` unnder `This PC` is a different matter. A drag-and-drop may have inadvertently merged it with your profile folder. Can you locate any files/folders you know were in `Downloads` and determine their current location?

See if either of these commands open your downloads folder (Type in `Run...` dialog or Explorer Address bar):

- `shell:Local Downloads`
- `shell:Downloads`

Will wait to see if first part works and wait for additional info...

---

### Edit:

Looking at that error message, Explorer is looking for `Downloads` in its default location, and creating a folder named "Downloads" in your user profile folder should fix the error. Then locate the missing contents ( most likely in your user profile folder ) and move them to the newly-created folder.

---

### Edit 2:

If you're sure of the status of the `ReadONly` attribute, eg. by viewing a directory listing (`R`in the `Mode`column):

```
PS C:\...\keith>gci -ad


    Directory: C:\Users\keith


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-r---         1/21/2022   3:11 AM                .dotnet
d-----         1/19/2022   6:05 AM                .nuget
d-----         10/8/2020   7:33 PM                .vscode
d-r---         4/17/2021  11:48 PM                3D Objects
```

You can set the `ReadOnly` attribute for a folder using:

- `(gi <Path>) += 'ReadOnly'` -- where path can be absolute, relative, or `.` to specify the current directory.

And clear it using:

- `(gi <Path>) += 'ReadOnly'`

But if you're unsure of the state of the flag, use bitwise operations to set or clear an attrubute:

- Set:

  ```
   (gi .).Attributes = (gi .).Attributes -bor [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly
  ```
- Clear:

  ```
   (gi .).Attributes = (gi .).Attributes -band ! [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly
  ```
- To list the `[System.IO.FileAttributes]` enumeration, use the seemingly naval-gazing method invocation:

  ```
   [System.IO.FileAttributes]::GetNames([System.IO.FileAttributes])
  ```

```
PS C:\> [System.IO.FileAttributes]::GetNames([System.IO.FileAttributes])
ReadOnly
Hidden
System
Directory
Archive
Device
Normal
Temporary
SparseFile
ReparsePoint
Compressed
Offline
NotContentIndexed
Encrypted
IntegrityStream
NoScrubData
PS C:\>
```

Comment: When I go to C/Users/Downloads and click for path it shows C:\Users\Bir Bahadur this as path but when I do as you said, it gives this error "Get-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that
accepts argument 'Bahadur*'.
At line:1 char:2
+ (gi *Bir Bahadur*).Attributes -= 'Read-Only'
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Ite
   m], ParameterBindingException

Comment: WITH DOUBLE QUOTES                                                                                                                                C:\Users> (gi *"Bir Bahadur"*).Attributes -= 'Read-Only'
Cannot convert value "Read-Only" to type
"System.IO.FileAttributes". Error: "Unable to match the
identifier name Read-Only to a valid enumerator name.
Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again: ReadOnly, Hidden, System, Directory, Archive, Device,Normal, Temporary, SparseFile, ReparsePoint, Compressed,Offline, NotContentIndexed, Encrypted, IntegrityStream,NoScrubData"

Comment: After Changing The "Read-Only" to "ReadOnly" it works great, Thank You.

Comment: Thank You :) Very Much, You are awesome.

Comment: How can we remove the read-only, I have applied Read-Only by mistake to a folder and now I cannot see it in my D: Drive please Help

Comment: Sorry about the typo on `ReadOnly`. Will edit. Will add info on setting & clearing as well.

Comment: @KeithMiller _(This doesn't have any bearing on the answer's content, as I think it's a great answer)_ Something else would have to have been done on the OP's system, as simply copying a `desktop.ini` config file into `%UserProfile%` does not result in what the OP is experiencing _(I can't replicate it)_; do you know under what conditions this would result in the OP's issue?

Comment: @JW0914:  Most likely, attemptinng to relocate the target folder via the `Move` buttom on the `Location` tab. Many users mistakenly relocate "one level too high" because they assume the wizard creates the actual target.